# Hibernate Search 6.0.2.Final with opendistro

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I have a `Spring Boot 2.4.2` application integrated with `Hibernate Search 6.0.2.Final`

When using standard `elasticsearch` everything works fine (read/write) on persisting new entities. The index also gets created as expected `myindex-000001` based on the default `simple` index strategy.

However, when I switched the backend to `opendistro` (latest) I only see a single index created by the name `myindex-write` (different that the expected `myindex-000001`).
The write operations work fine as expected (due to the suffix `-write`), however the read operations fail with the error:

```json
root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index [myindex-read]",
        "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id": "myindex-read",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "myindex-read"
      }
    ]
```

`GET /_cat/aliases` on `opendistro` show that there are no aliases for the index.

What is the best possible way to resolve this? `no-alias` strategy shown [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-indexlayout)? The downside of using `no-alias` is the lack of blue-green deployment like re-indexing. Is `custom` index strategy the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the above issues were caused because I had set `hibernate.search.schema_management.strategy` to `none`. The indexes need to be created manually, as mentioned in the docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-schema-management-strategy)